# "sudo start mysql" results in an error

Tags: mysql

```
minzaw@Dell-PC:~$ sudo start mysql
[sudo] password for minzaw: 
start: *Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused*
minzaw@Dell-PC:~$ sudo restart mysql
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Connection refused, do you have a firewall or something that is restricting the internet?

Comment: ubuntu version  above 15.5,

Comment: @user486555: That's no Ubuntu release I've heard of before. In 2015 we had 15.04 and 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Ubuntu 15.04 or newer try `sudo systemctl start mysql`, or in general `sudo systemctl <action> <service-name>`to control daemons.